# When should you mess with Ant Buildfiles?

Tags: ant, build, build-process

On large team projects, I've needed to manually edit the Ant Buildfile. On small programs I've written from scratch, I haven't needed to make or edit any sort of helper files for the build (e.g. never written a Buildfile for Hello World"). So my questions are:

1. On those smaller projects, how is the program ever being built?
2. What kinds of projects will build automatically, and what kinds of projects require a Buildfile that needs to be manually edited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No project built with Ant will ever build automatically without creating a build file.

Ant doesn't do anything without a build file.

Maybe your IDE generates one for you, or maybe you're not even using Ant to build your small project.

Answer (score 2):

The  build.xml came first, IDE support followed.

IDE will generate a default build.xml file for you. You will have to customise it to adjust to  any custome requirement.

Actually any work done out side IDE would require a decent build.xml file. For example code coverage using a different tool that what your IDE gave , static code analysis like findbugs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very helpful. Protip: 'messing up' means something different to 'messing with'.

Comment: @ chm052 : thanks for the correction. removed that from answer.